# Command mode input are not accepted in enumitem package

Tags: enumerate

I will try to pass the list label value like `Step 1` through the new command for the following format `\newcommand\grablabel{Step 1}`.

But the `enumerate` package is not supported the command values like `\grablabel`. The output is render all the values are `Step 1`

I have placed my `MWE` and output for your reference.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\let\enumerate\compactenum
\let\itemize\compactitem

\makeatletter
\newcommand\grablabel{Step 1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First Example}

\begin{enumerate}[Step 1][4]

\item list 1

\item list 2

\item list 3

\item list 4

\end{enumerate}

\section{Second Example}

\begin{enumerate}[\grablabel][4]

\item list 1

\item list 2

\item list 3

\item list 4

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

The Output and my required output is mentioned the below output image:

[image]

So, I need to pass the value through command mode. Could you please check and advice how to get the required output through the command mode.

Comment: What does this question has to do with the enumitem package when you're not using it? Drop paralist and switch to enumitem, though you should not expect `\grablabel` to work, as the parser does not understand it.

Comment: @daleif you are correct i have replaced the style compactenum to enumerate. So, the parser is not working properly. Thanks for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must expand `\grablabel` before passing it to `\compactenum`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[flushleft,alwaysadjust]{paralist}
\let\itemize\compactitem

\renewcommand\enumerate[1][\relax]
{\ifx\relax#1\def\next{\compactenum}\else
  \def\next{\expandafter\compactenum\expandafter[#1]}\fi
  \next}{\endenumerate}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\grablabel{Step 1}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{First Example}

\begin{enumerate}[Step 1][4]

\item list 1

\item list 2

\item list 3

\item list 4

\end{enumerate}

\section{Second Example}

\begin{enumerate}[\grablabel][4]

\item list 1

\item list 2

\item list 3

\item list 4

\end{enumerate}

\section{Third Example (no options)}

\begin{enumerate}

\item list 1

\item list 2

\item list 3

\item list 4

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution is working awesome. Thank you for your solution